# How do I check if a mobile number is on WhatsApp or not with programming?

Tags: web, web-applications, whatsapp, whatsapi

I wanted to build a web-based system using which you will come to know whether the mobile number is registered with WhatsApp or not? It's just to check whether the number entered in textbox have WhatsApp account or not? 
I tried finding resources regarding the same but unable to get any solution on it, please share some link for reference so, I can implement it and get to the final result.

Comment: is there is anyway? to get solution for this.

Comment: Refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/contacts

Comment: https://checkwa.online/wp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Whatsapp API through Wassenger of Waboxap to send a text message and via webhook service like Loggly determine if the message was delivered. The person will however get a message, which might cause them to block you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, earlier there was such an opportunity to do just in the API officially from Meta through the method /contacts. But starting in v2.43, there will be changes to the behavior of the contacts endpoint. Responses for status will change. Regardless of whether a user has WhatsApp, it will always return valid for status in the response and a wa_id. There is no guarantee that the returned wa_id will be valid. These changes are applicable for both direct responses, as well as webhook responses for non-blocking calls
I found a way to do it without posting (so as not to be blocked), while still doing it in bulk:

```
    
    const request = require('request');
    
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://gate.whapi.cloud/contacts?token=123',
      headers: {accept: 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'},
      body: {
        blocking: 'wait',
        force_check: true,
        contacts: ['{{Recipient-WA-ID}}', '{{Recipient-WA-ID}}']
      },
      json: true
    };
    
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
    
      console.log(body);
    });
```

I replaced my token, but I think the point is clear. It really cuts down on the time I have to spend on mailings. And of course, it keeps me from getting blocked.
This is where this method https://whapi.cloud/docs#/Contacts/checkPhones